# /bin/ld cannot find lstdc++ but libstdc++.so does exist

Tags: g++

Given error:

```
/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
```

I used the following commands:

```
locate libstdc++.so
```

And its output:

```
$ locate libstdc++ | grep libstdc++.so
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/libstdc++.so
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/32/libstdc++.so
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.py
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.pyc
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.pyo
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.py
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.pyc
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.pyo
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.py
/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.pyc
/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.pyo
```

Clearly libstdc++.so exists. Why it gives that error?

Comment: what is your compile command ?

Comment: edit the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, add the path of libstdc++.so to it.

Comment: You shouldn't need to explicitly link to libstdc++, let the compiler do it for you

Comment: @MERN it's a large project using makefile at root, and every module uses its own like cmake or make. I don't know which gcc command it uses.

Comment: @Yves that could work

Comment: I finally solved it by create a soft link libstdc++.so to libstdc++.so.6.0.19

Comment: apt-get install locate